# Cmd shows "...unexpected at this time" response while calling batch file with parentheses in it's path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Some days ago I've found out that some commands in my batch scripts stopped working because file paths can't be resolved.

E.g. for command

```
D:\Work\build>call "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7
(64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\bin\acompc"
-source-path flash/src/ -include-classes "com.domain.SomeClass"
-swf-version=20 -output SomeClass.swc
```

I get the response

```
\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\bin\..) was unexpected at this time.
```

P.S. changed the example text to avoid any more talks about forwardslashes and backslashes;)

Also, here you are, the same call caught in JPG: [image: JPG].

I assume that the cause is in parentheses and spaces contained together in the file path. Unfortunately, neither escaping them with ^ symbol or covering the whole string with additional single qoutes ' doesn't help.

Comment: You have forward slashes in your code and back slashes in your example output, and the actual paths aren't the same as shown as `bin\..` is not in your code.  It's hard to know what you're actually doing.

Comment: @foxidrive Actually, I'm just making the represented call and getting the represented result. And what do you mean under "the actual paths aren't the same as shown"? All the paths are correct and have not been changed since I've used this batch script for the last time.

Comment: As you can see `bin\..` is not in your code, but it is in your example screen output.

Comment: @foxidrive Ah, you are talking about dots. Yes, you are right, they appear only in the response (IMHO to make text shorter).

Comment: You can replace forward slashes with backslashes in the file path and see if it works.

Comment: I could bet that you did NOT entered such command at the command-line (although you want we think that), but such command is placed in a Batch .bat file _and_ is placed inside an `if` or `for` command...

Comment: @Aacini we can discuss the sum of your bet and then I'll add a screenshot of my cmd window:)

Comment: If it is entered on the command line, why do you use "call"? You can launch the batch file by itself or use the cmd command.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Actually, it doesn't matter. At the very beginning I've stated that my **batch** scripts appears to be broken. Also calling this single command string gives the same result - http://joxi.ru/DmBLylfN8836AP.

Comment: Are all of these lines on a single line in the .bat script? If not, then you need line continuation characters. You must change the / to \ in the executable filename. While Windows can internally handle /, `cmd` does not. Maybe others will, but I do not think I will visit joxi.ru. Please post the information here.

Comment: @Liturgist done. Also, forward-, back- or even double backslashes are all the same for win cmd. (And joxi.ru is always OK, it's just a screenshot sharing service:).

Comment: In the following link, they suggest turning "echo on" to see what happens in the batch file, and point to a possible problem with the CLASSPATH variable: http://www.coderanch.com/t/517970/tools/ANT-unexpected-time

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you for the link. Toggling echo mode is useless for me because I'm already trying to handle issue with a single command string. Also, CLASSPATH var is not set on my machine and PATH var is OK (contains no quotes).

Comment: The error message comes from the execution in the batch file or from the command line itself?

Comment: @ConnorsFan from the both cases.

Comment: OK, I thought that "acompc" was a batch file. I now understand that it is a DOS command. Sorry.

Comment: @ConnorsFan you were right, `acompc` is actually `acompc.bat`, but the described issue comes not from inside of it, but from the calling string itself - I'm unable to pass file's location to `call` command to run it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105443/discussion-between-connorsfan-and-vyacheslav-orlovsky).

Comment: press `alt+printscreen` to print the current window instead of cropping out like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ConnorsFan I've figured out the cause. The issue appeared from one of batch files called recoursively from `acompc.bat`. All of them use `~dp0` param to set some vars and make further calls.

So, in `compc.bat` there is a string

```
if "x%AIR_SDK_HOME%"=="x"  (set AIR_SDK_HOME=%~dp0..) else echo Using AIR SDK: %AIR_SDK_HOME%
```

Nevermind AIR_SDK_HOME variable have been set already or not, you'll get the same problem while calling this batch from a folder containing parentheses in it's path (`Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)` in my case).

Because it was impossible to fix the issue from my own batch file, I had to cover the whole assignment with double quotes:

```
if "x%AIR_SDK_HOME%"=="x"  (set "AIR_SDK_HOME=%~dp0..") else echo Using AIR SDK: %AIR_SDK_HOME%
```

And that did the job!)

Comment: This means that, in the bottom line, I was right: the command that cause the problem (`set` in this case) is placed in a Batch .bat file _and_ is placed inside an `if` or `for` command! Right?

Comment: Absolutely. And that's why I've up-voted your comment.